# Contact ESD protection vs Air gap ESD protection

Tags: pcb-design, esd

There many ESD diodes available in market for ESD protection from connectors or 'touch surfaces' of product.

But how about air gap ESD attack? What if I have large PCB with connectors at the end, ESD happens through air in the middle of PCB. What kind of protection can be implemented in the circuit design or in PCB layout for this attack?

Does it matter if IC is at the edge(Upper or lower) of PCB or in the center? Air gap ESD attack can also happen from Z direction.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Periphery or I/O connector ESD protection is indeed ineffective against ESD events in the middle of a board.

That is why ESD sensitive circuitry is typically enclosed in a housing.

And why it is recommended that repair, maintenance, or development work on such a device occur only in an ESD-protected work environment.

Many modern ESD-sensitive semiconductors include protection at the level of individually I/O pins, but for particularly sensitive circuits, or those where there's a fear that ESD might degrade performance without creating an immediately recognizable failure (eg, high performance RF/microwave parts), then those precautions would hold at least for production (vs possibly, development) examples.